# Unloading rJava and/or restarting JVM

Tags: java, r, jvm, cran, rjava

I would like to use `rJava` in combination with `mcparallel` but obviously [the JVM cannot be forked](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2013-November/067960.html). Therefore a separate JVM instance needs to be initiated for each child process, e.g:

```
library(rJava)
library(parallel)
myfile <-  system.file("tests", "test_import.xlsx", package = "xlsx")

#This works:
mccollect(mcparallel({
  #Automatically initiates JVM in child
  xlsx::read.xlsx(myfile, 1)
}))
```

However the problem in my case is that the JVM has already been initiated in the (main) parent process as well. This makes it impossible to use `rJava` in the child process:

```
#init JVM in parent
.jinit()

#Doesn't work anymore
mccollect(mcparallel({
  xlsx::read.xlsx(myfile, 1)
}))
```

So what I really need is a way to shutdown/kill and restart the JVM in the child process. Simply  `detach("package:rJava", unload = TRUE)` doesn't seem to do the trick. The `force.init` parameter doesn't seem to result in a restart either:

```
#Also doesn't work:
.jinit()
mccollect(mcparallel({
  .jinit(force.init = TRUE)
  xlsx::read.xlsx(myfile, 1)
}))
```

Is there some way I can forcefully shutdown/kill the JVM in order to reinitiate it in the child process?

Comment: When I had a similar need in the past, I ended up implementing a main method in the Java code to allow execution from R as an external program using 'system'.

Comment: Just for the record, a github issue was opened for this: https://github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/25

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to run expressions using rJava in parallel based on running the parallel processes to get and assemble all results **BEFORE** you load the rJava library in the main process. As the main R process has not initiated jvm then java is started in each single subprocess and this particular instance will die together with subprocess as well.

```
# Rsession started
library(parallel)
myfile <-  system.file("tests", "test_import.xlsx", package = "xlsx")
e <- expression({
require(rJava)
require(xlsx)
read.xlsx(myfile, 1)
})
p <- mcparallel(e)
q <- mcparallel(e)
pq <- mccollect(list(p, q))

# again to check reproducibility
p <- mcparallel(e)
q <- mcparallel(e)
pq2 <- mccollect(list(p, q))
identical(unname(pq),unname(pq2))

# see the result if it is the right content and not tryerr
pq

# now the main continues ...
# and if necessary even load rJava
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. In my application I do need `rJava` in the parent process.