# Running 'xlsx' processes in parallel, using the 'parallel' R package

Tags: r, parallel-processing, xlsx

I have a project where I need to process some data from an Excel file with R. I must use  the 'xlsx' package because of some specific functions.

First, I wrote a script, which works as expected without errors.

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx4096m") #for extra memory
library(xlsx)

wb <- loadWorkbook(file = "my_excel.xlsx")
sheet1 <- getSheets(wb)[[1]]
rows <- getRows(sheet1)

make_df <- function (x) {
  cells <- getCells(rows[x])
  styles <- sapply(cells, getCellStyle)

  cellColor <- function(style) {
    fg  <- style$getFillForegroundXSSFColor()
    rgb <- tryCatch(fg$getRgb(), error = function(e) NULL)
    rgb <- paste(rgb, collapse = "")
    return(rgb)
  }

  colors <- sapply(styles, cellColor)

  if (!any(colors == "ff0000")) {
    df[nrow(df) + 1, ] <- sapply(cells, getCellValue) #I define this 'df' somewhere in the code; this part could be improved 
  }
}

df <- sapply(1 : length(rows), make_df)
```

In short, I am looking for the rows in Excel where there are no red-colored cells, [like described here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/when-life-gives-you-coloured-cells-make-categories/). The problem is that the Excel file is very big, and it takes a lot of time to process.

What I'd like to do is to run the row checking in parallel, to be more efficient, so I added:

```
cl = makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
clusterEvalQ(cl=cl, c(library(xlsx))) #sharing the package with the workers
clusterExport(cl = cl, c('rows')) #sharing the 'row' variable with the workers

df <- parSapply(cl, 1 : length(rows), make_df)
```

And after running this, I get the following error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
7 nodes produced errors; first error: RcallMethod: attempt to call a method of a NULL object.
```

I tried the parallelization with another example, without using 'xlsx' functions, and it worked.
After some digging, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337383/unloading-rjava-and-or-restarting-jvm) which offered somewhat of an answer (more like a workaround), but I can't seem to be able to implement it.

Is there a clean way to do what I'm trying to do here?

If not, then what would be the best solution in this case?

Comment: Why don't you use `readxl` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/readxl.pdf]) for reading Excel files? It doesn't need Java and in general more convenient to use. Is it because you need to extract cell styles?

Comment: Because the cells in the excel are color coded, and I am interested in those cells, that aren't red (I am checking this inside R). I can easily achieve this using the `xlsx` package. I don't think I can do this, using `readxl`.

Comment: Could you try sharing your custom function `make_df` with each worker? You will need to copy-paste the entire function into `clustEvalQ(cl, { copy-paste })`.